# Mysql Instance in google cloud - Communications link failure

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, google-cloud-sql

I am getting the following error while connecting  to the MySql instance in google cloud.

The connection to the database is over a private IP.

The same setup is working on a normal co-located server.

I am able to use the mysql client to connect to the database over the private IP.

The application being deployed is a Spring based application.

2020-07-30 09:31:03,369 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (JCA PoolFiller) IJ000610: Unable to fill pool: java:jboss/datasources/ACADEMY: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.22.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:345)
at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.22.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:352)
at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.22.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:287)
at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.22.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1322)
at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.22.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.fillTo(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1142)
at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.22.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.PoolFiller.run(PoolFiller.java:97)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
at com.mysql@8.0.20//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
at com.mysql@8.0.20//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
at com.mysql@8.0.20//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
at com.mysql@8.0.20//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
at com.mysql@8.0.20//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
at com.mysql@8.0.20//com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197)
at org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters@1.4.22.Final//org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.createLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:321)
... 6 more
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [JDBC socket factory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#_spring_jdbc). You also need to enable Cloud SQL Admin API in the project, and install / authenticate the Cloud SDK before using the socket factory. Follow the instruction in the link above to add the library as a dependency and to create a JDBC URL